# Finding the Maclaurin expansion of the 6th derivative of a function

Tags: calculus, derivatives, taylor-expansion

Let $$f(x)= \sin \left(\ln \left(1+\frac{x^2}{2}\right)\right)$$

Find the Maclaurin expansion of $f^{(6)}$ with order 3.

We know that :

$$ f(x) = \sum^\infty_{k=0} \frac{f^{(6)} (0) }{k!} x^k $$

In a neighborhood of $0$, therefore

$$f^{(6)}(x)=\frac{d^6}{dx^6} \left(\sum^\infty _{k=0} \frac{f^{(k)} (0) }{k!} x^k\right) = 6\sum^\infty _{k=0} \frac{f^{(k)} (0) }{k!} x^{k-6} $$

Is this the right way to proceed? I have my doubts about this because I don't know if the derivative should be regarded as a scalar or as a function of $x$, I guess it is fine in this way though because it's just the derivative of a function applied to a certain point $x_0=0$.
So to proceed I'll simply need to expand the function $f$ until I have $ o(x^{9})$ and then I can proceed to subtract $6$ to each power and multiply by $6$.

Comment: What is $\frac {d^{6}}{dx^{6}}x^{k}$? Write this down for $k<6$ and $k \ge 6$.

Comment: @geetha290krm 0 , $ 6x^{k-6}$?

Comment: @MassimilianoMessina No; try finding the sixth derivative of something like $x^{13}$ first.

Comment: $13 *12* 11* 10* 9 *8 x^{13-6},$ so $\frac{6!}{(k-6)!} x^{k-6}$?

Comment: No. You won't have $x^{13}$.

Comment: Another issue is about the case for the $ x^2 $ term for example in the original expansion: What do you state currently happens to it and what actually happens to it when you differentiate it  6 times?

Comment: @J.Dmaths It gets 0

Comment: @MassimilianoMessina Right, but in your sum above , it suggests that it differentiates to become an $x^{-4} $term, right? So any modification to that result should also include this idea.

Comment: @J.Dmaths i already underground It Is wrong, It should be like 0 for k<6 and k!/(k-6)! x$^{k-6}$ for k≥6 right?

Answer (score 1):

What you are required to get is the approximation

$$
f^{(6)}(x) \approx f^{(6)}(0) + f^{(7)}(0)x + \frac{f^{(8)}(0)}{2} x^2 + \frac{f^{(9)}(0)}{6} x^3 = 15.
$$

So, this just boils down to computing $f^{(k)}(0), k = 6, \cdots 9$.

Comment: Importantly to note: You do not need to differentiate explicitly to find  $f^{(k)}(0)$ for those k.